# will someone look at this background issue in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, background

I cant get my main slider div to be transparent in IE, it show "white"?

http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek

Answer (score 0):

Add this style

```
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
opacity:0;
```

to your `ul#slider`

Comment: nope.. I'm using the cycle plugin and Its just not holding its opacity, IE developer says its applying background-color:#fff somehow to the li tags inside of the cycle

Comment: i've just checked again. yep, it somehow added inline style to the li tags :(

Answer (score 0):

I looked at it and I see the inline styles added to the li tags, probably by your jquery script. Is the transparancy somehting you are adding in, or is it from the script? I think you need to use a different filter for IE8 though.

`-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";`

This *should* do it for IE8, but it's untested and just code I pulled from google since I couldn't remember the exact details. But I think this is your problem if you can get it to apply properly. Also you need to put this filter statement before the old style `filter:alpha()` statement or it won't work right.